# Using PHP to print directly to a network printer that is not installed on the server?

Tags: php, printing, fsockopen

I'm trying to build a helper tool that will be used for testing networked printers.

Server calculates printer IP by looking up header information for IP address of the computer that sent the request, and changing last octet to match printer.

So idea is to save test page to file (rendered by proper driver). The installer would open a web page, select location and send print job directly to TCP port 9100 of the local printer.

This is necessary because installer has no access to the local system other than a web browser.

Since the printer is not installed on the server, the print job could be sent from saved file using fsocks (telnet?)

I was googling for some time, but I only found examples for printers that are already installed on the server.

Help?

Comment: so you want to print to a printer that is outside of your network? Then wouldn't you need to forward that printers ports?